# android, Accessing just to update of SDK

Tags: android, file, version

Accessing to android website is blocked in my country by Google and programmers who are staying in my country are not able to download SDK and use android website.

I have bypassed this problem by uploading SDK on my host and let programmers to download SDK from my website, also I am translating articles of "Dev Guide" page.
Now the problem is, Internet speed in my country is low and it is not possible for programmers download SDK each time it is updated (around 2.4G each time).

Now the question, How can I understand which files are added or changed in each update (version) of android in order to upload just those files?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for very good cause, but I dont understand why Google has done this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a diff of the zip files that Google provides. Just do a search for 'zip diff' or 'jar diff' since jar files are zip files, should give you some leads to utils to do the work.

Only thing I can think that may cause Google to block access is if there are export restrictions for the products involved. Or the ISP has blocked access to the Android website.